# Show averages of a dataset, different date/time ranges

Tags: sql-server, moving-average

DB: MS SQL Server 11.0.3156.

I have a table where I record periodic data values.   The key columns are:
fldObjectGUID (varchar), fldDataTimestamp (datetime), fldConfigItem (varchar), fldConfigItemValue (numeric)

I want to retrieve data for a different time frame (day, week, month).  But to keep the number of returned data pints to a manageable number (e.g. less < 350), Therefore, I'd like to get averages.

For example:

- Day - Return all Data (already got this!)
- Week - Return the data in hourly average values (e.g. there would be 24 * 1 Hour Averages, * 7 days)
- Month - Return the data in 3-hourly average values (e.g. 8 * Average
  over 3 hours, * 30)
- Yearly - Return the data in daily average values (e.g. 1 * Average
  over 24 hours, * 365)

A small example of the data set is shown here:

```
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
+ fldObjectGUID | fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp | fldConfigItem     | fldConfigItemValue |
+ 40010000      | 2015-06-16 18:20:48.000   | ICMPResponseTime  |   4.00             |
+ 40010000      | 2015-06-16 19:22:00.000   | ICMPResponseTime  |   15.00            |
+ 40010000      | 2015-06-16 20:22:14.000   | ICMPResponseTime  |   4.00             |
+ 40010000      | 2015-06-17 17:35:19.000   | ICMPResponseTime  |   6.00             |
+ 40010000      | 2015-06-17 18:36:26.000   | ICMPResponseTime  |   4.00             |
+ 40010000      | 2015-06-28 02:18:31.000   | ICMPResponseTime  |   19.00            |
+ 40010000      | 2015-06-28 03:18:54.000   | ICMPResponseTime  |   9.00             |
+ 40010000      | 2015-06-02 17:25:16.000   | ICMPResponseTime  |   3.00             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Data is added for an object (fldObjectGUID) at different rates.  This could be one row every 5 minutes or 1 one row every hour.  There can be gaps in the data (hours or even days).  I want to graph the fldConfigItemValue data for each object over different time frames;  Day (last 24 hours), Week, Month and Year.  The periods of the returned data don't need to be exact.  So,  a month could just be the last 30 days, or just 1 calendar month back from today's date.

The SQL only needs to return data for a single fldObjectGUID and fldConfigItem combination - I'll then amend the SQL at run-time to get the data for the required object/configitem.

There may be gaps in the data, so no data points within a given period.  So, the return value can be zero.

I'm retrieving data using Classic ASP, creating the SQL statement and parsing the results.  I could achieve the result programatically in my ASP code.  So for the 'Week' required set,  I could make repeated calls to the DB, using the AVERAGE function, and a WHERE clause to retrieve a subset of records (NOW to NOW - 1 hour). Store the value, then repeat using a WHERE clause for (NOW - 1 hour to NOW - 2 Hours).  And just step back in time until I've got all the values for a week.  The 'Month' and 'Yearly' routines would be the same, just different timeframes in the WHERE clauses.

However, even to me, this seems a clumsy way of doing it and just one SQL routine (or a different SQL routine for Week, Month and Year) must be quicker and / or more elegant.

At the moment,  I have some SQL (from StackOverflow?) that I thought might work and I have my code build up the SQL for the 'Month' view like this (I've hard-coded the fldObjectGUID and fldConfigItem in the example, to make the example clearer):

```
SELECT      top 30 convert(date, l.fldDataTimestamp) as 'fldDataTimestamp_result', l.fldConfigItemValue, l.fldConfigItemValue
FROM        tblObjectHealthCheckData_Historic l
            INNER JOIN  (
            SELECT    MIN(fldDataTimestamp) first_timestamp
            FROM     tblObjectHealthCheckData_Historic
            where fldObjectGUID = '10050400' and fldConfigItem = 'AvailableRAM'
            group by Convert(Date, fldDataTimestamp)
            ) sub_l ON (sub_l.first_timestamp = l.fldDataTimestamp)
where fldObjectGUID = '10050400' and l.fldConfigItem = 'AvailableRAM'
order by fldDataTimestamp desc
```

But this gets just the first data point for each day (as you can guess,  whilst I do understand SQL and programming, they are a hobby, not something I do for a living) and so I'm struggling to fix this code.

I'm assuming that people agree, it's more efficient doing this in code that making many separate SQL calls - but can anyone help?

Comment: When I say I 'understand SQL' - I mean, from a basic viewpoint.  I Wanted to clarify that in case it came across wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try with DATEPART function, this way you can get different parts of the fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp and then AVG field fldConfigItemValue.

This goes down to a single Hour of your timestamp (could be minutes, check MSDN for [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) in T-SQL), so if you wish to get daily averages per week then you need to include:

```
day_fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp
week_fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp
```

this will Average for each day inside each week.

Below example shows average per month - mind the year, if you have more than a years worth of data make sure you include year_fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp etc.

```
WITH PartsTable As 
(
    SELECT
        fldObjectGUID
        , fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp
        , fldConfigItem
        , fldConfigItemValue
        , DATEPART(HOUR, fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp) As hour_fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp
        , DATEPART(DAY, fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp) As day_fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp
        , DATEPART(WEEK, fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp) As week_fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp
        , DATEPART(MONTH, fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp) As month_fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp
        , DATEPART(YEAR, fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp) As year_fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp
    FROM
        YourLogTable
    --WHERE
    -- Perhaps set a limit here to not get a huge set in the first step.    
)
SELECT
    COUNT(1) As setcount /* Shows how many rows are in each AVG calculation. */
    , fldObjectGUID
    , fldConfigItem
    , month_fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp /* Change this column for specific span you're intrested in. */
    , AVG(fldConfigItemValue) As avg_fldConfigItemValue
FROM
    PartsTable
GROUP BY
    fldObjectGUID
    , fldConfigItem
    , month_fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp /* Change this column for specific span you're intrested in. */
;
```

One final note: make sure you include month_, week_ etc. column in both SELECT and GROUP BY.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to read the (long) post and come up with a solution - I really appreciate it.  Let me read through the code so that I understand it (as much as I can) and then I'll try it out.    Thanks again - I'll mark this as answered (but hope that you can help if I stumble slightly with the implementation).

Comment: Firstly - thank you again.  Apart from one typo - which you put in just to test me :-) - that worked straight away.   It's exactly what I was looking for and you wrote it in a way that meant I could understand how you arrived at the answer (so a great learning exercise for me and others).  A perfect reply.   Wish I could give you some more Rep for this.   Regards,  Ian

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I hope you can tweak and play around some more because I did not answer your part about this -- (e.g. 8 * Average over 3 hours, * 30) and other examples you specified. But with different DATEPARTs and the GROUP BY you can achieve a lot. Curious though where is the typo?

Comment: Hi.  Yes,  I'm going to spend some time tweeking, but I can see that this is definitely the way to do it.  Typo?  Please don't think I'm being critical - just thought I'd mention it in case someone (with even less SQL experience than me) wanted to use the solution.  It's just "DATEPART(xxx, fldConfigItemValue)" should be "DATEPART(xxx, fldRecordUpdatedTimestamp)" - completely understandable as you were writing blind, without my DB to test on.   Again - thanks for the help.  Regards,  Ian

Comment: Oh, very nice, no offense taken - I edited my answer for other people stumbling by. Yeah I did this "blind" or actually on a different table and then just replaced your fields.